# Unbinding service in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-service

I block since 3 days on a problem of binding/unbinding services, i pass my old activities in fragments. Binding service in fragment seems to work properly but unbindingservice crash, can you help me ?

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        //On attache la vue au service
        getActivity().bindService(
                new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), GeoLocatingService.class),
                connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        super.onStart();

    }





    @Override
    public void onStop() {
         //On detache la vue du service
            if(myService!=null){
                getActivity().getApplicationContext().unbindService(connection);
            }

        super.onStop();
    }
```

Error log :

> 09-23 00:39:00.541: E/AndroidRuntime(17970): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   09-23 00:39:00.541: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered:
>   com.timo.geolocalisation.Dashboard_Fragment$3@40557f58 09-23
>   00:39:00.541: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):    at
>   android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:891)
>   09-23 00:39:00.541: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):  at
>   android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:925) 09-23
>   00:39:00.541: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):    at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:352)
>   09-23 00:39:00.541: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):  at
>   com.timo.geolocalisation.Dashboard_Fragment.onStop(Dashboard_Fragment.java:220)
>   09-23 00:39:00.541: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStop(Fragment.java:1651) 09-23
>   00:39:00.541: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):    at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:979)
>   09-23 00:39:00.541: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.detachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1258)
>   09-23 00:39:00.541: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:667)
>   09-23 00:39:00.541: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
>   09-23 00:39:00.541: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
>   09-23 00:39:00.541: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):  at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) 09-23
>   00:39:00.541: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 09-23
>   00:39:00.541: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 09-23 00:39:00.541:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(17970):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691) 09-23
>   00:39:00.541: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-23
>   00:39:00.541: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 09-23 00:39:00.541:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(17970):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
>   09-23 00:39:00.541: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605) 09-23
>   00:39:00.541: E/AndroidRuntime(17970):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Are you trying to stop or unbind the service twice anywhere? From the logs it appears like the service was previously stopped.

Comment: It is stopped only in method on stop in 3 fragments, i don't understand for why it can't stop. I look maybe a context problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears like the `Service` is stopped in one of the three `Fragment`s and when you try to stop the `Service` in other two `Fragment`s you get this error.

From Android documentation it says:

> Note that multiple calls to `Context.startService()` do not nest (though they do result in multiple corresponding calls to `onStartCommand()`), so no matter how many times it is started a service will be stopped once `Context.stopService()` or `stopSelf()` is called; however, services can use their `stopSelf(int)` method to ensure the service is not stopped until started intents have been processed.

So, check whether one of the `Fragment` is stopping the `Service`, or you can start and stop the service in the `FragmentActivity`s! Let the `Activity` handle this and pass a reference to the `Fragments` if they need the `Service` too.

Comment: I must to push all features.I think the right thing is to implement listeners on my 3 fragments to refresh view if needed by the result of the service ?